# Derivative $f(x)={{x \ln (x)} \over 1+ \ln (x)}$ and $f(x)=\ln( \ln x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)={{x \ln (x)} \over 1+ \ln (x)}$

Find $df\over dx$

My answer :

$${(\ln(x)+1).(\ln(x)+1)-ln(x)}\over {(1+\ln(x))^2}$$

$${(\ln(x)+1)^2-\ln(x)}\over {(1+\ln(x))^2}$$

True or false ? And if true how can I simple the answer?

And what about :

$$f(x)=\ln\ln(x)$$

I think :

$${df\over dx}= {{1\over x}\over \ln x}.{1\over x}$$

$${df\over dx}= {1\over x^2 \ln x}$$

But the teacher said

$${df\over dx}= {1\over x \ln x}$$

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Apply chain rule in second

Comment: Simplifying the derivative of the first expression: ${{(\ln(x)+1)^2-\ln(x)}\over {(1+\ln(x))^2}}=1-{ {\ln(x)}\over {(1+\ln(x))^2}}$

Comment: First part is true you can write it $1-\frac{\ln x}{(1+\ln x)^2}$

Comment: Second one: Chain rule :  $ (g(h(x))'=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x) . $  With  $ g=h=\ln$

Answer (score 2):

For second part ,
$$y=\ln \ln x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln \ln x)}{d(\ln x)}.\frac{d(\ln x)}{d(x)}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\ln x}.\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second exercise use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$f(g(x))=\ln(\ln x)$

$\left( f(g(x))\right)'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

Thus $\left( \ln \ln x\right)'=\frac{1}{\ln x }\cdot \frac1x$

Answer (score 0):

your first part is coorect .And that is your final answer and i dont think so there is a simpler way to write this other than

$$\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{[1+\ln(x)]^2-\ln(x)}{[1+\ln(x)]^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}= 1 - \frac{\ln(x)}{[1+\ln(x)]^2}$$

And for second part:

$$\mathbf{f(x)=ln(ln(x))}$$

so by taking derivative

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{\ln(x)} .\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(x))$$

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}. \frac{1}{x}.\frac{d}{dx}(x)$$

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}.(1)$$
$$\mathbf{\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}.\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$$